# Enviar correos cuando cumple condicion PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while

amigo tengo una duda porque no soy muy avanzado en php.

El tema es el siguiente; necesito que un crobjob todos los días ejecute un php que haga una consulta a mysql y dependiendo de si cumple las condiciones que yo establezca debe traer los datos de las personas que cumplan con las condiciones definidas.

Mi base es sencilla, en ella mis usuarios definen una fecha y dejan un mensaje para que se los recuerde al correo electrónico, por ello requiero que en la consulta me traiga el correo de la persona y el mensaje que pidió que se le recordara.

lo anterior lo hago así:

```
//defino la fecha de hoy asi: $hoy= date('d-m-Y');
$verificar = mysqli_query($con,SELECT mensaje, correo, fec_rec FROM tareas WHERE cuando_recordar='$hoy' "") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Después arrastró los datos que necesito para el envío del correo, aqui necesito organizar el mensaje personalizado del usuario y el correo al que debo enviarlo así:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verificar))
    {
    $correo = $row['correo'];
    $mensaje = $row['mensaje'];
$fecharecordatorio = $row['fec_rec'];
    }
```

Ahora establezco la condición para que me haga el envío del correo al usuario o usuarios que cumplieron la condición así:

```
 If($hoy == $row['fec_mec'] ) { //Solo pongo las variables que me interesan del envío del mensaje lo demás no porque no lo veo necesario
//ejecuta el envío del email $from = $row['correo']; $mensaje =
 $row['mensaje'] ; }
```

El problema en mi razonamiento está mal lo se, porque si hay varios usuarios que cumplen la condicion y debe enviarseles correo, en mi razonamiento solamente envía al primer usuario que traiga la consulta pero a los demás no, quiero entender como puedo hacerlo y que por favor me den luces de cual es mi error, de antemano agradezco a las personas que me quieran ayudar a entender.

Comment: Esta consulta: `"SELECT mensaje, correo, fec_rec FROM tareas WHERE cuando_recordar='$hoy'"` te traería ya todas las filas a las que habría que mandar el e-mail. Entonces, no entiendo qué sentido tiene esta comparación posterior que mencionas en tu pregunta: `If($hoy == $row['fec_mec'] ) {`  ¿? En cuanto a tu duda de que sólo se enviaría al primer usuario, esto se resuelve preparando el envío del correo dentro del `while`, ahí se recorre cada fila de los resultados y por tanto puedes enviar el email a cada fila. Si es un mensaje genérico puedes preparar un solo correo y enviarlo con bcc.

Comment: Gracias tienes razon ya entendi como debo hacerlo dentro de while es mas ya hice la prueba y funciono perfectamente